# delete folder with .. (double dot) in its name

Tags: windows-7

How can I delete (remove) a folder (directory) with `..` in its name, like `blah..`?

Or for that matter how can such a folder be created in the first place?

What I've tried (none of these work)

- Delete from Explorer
- Rename from Explorer
- `del blah..` in Command Prompt
- `ren blah.. blah` in Command Prompt
- `del "blah.."`
- `rd blah..`
- `rd "blah.."`
- `del blah`
- `rd blah`

It looks like the name is "sanitised" before or within the Windows APIs, and operations are attempted on the `blah` folder (with `..` removed)

Comment: Try using `dir /X` and then try using the short 8.3 name if different.

Comment: @Yorik Thank you, good idea, using the short 8.3 name also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows lets you bypass the name processing that Win32 does, by using the `\\?\` prefix (see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx)). So the following path should work:

```
\\?\c:\users\whatever\wherever\blah..
```

(Yes, it must be an absolute path, since "current directory" is also a Win32 thing.)

I'm not sure which file managers accept such paths however. Many Win32 programs do, but Command Prompt built-in commands often don't, and PowerShell (being written in .NET) also doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, that works. The `rd` command accepted such a pathname

Answer (score 0):

Usually surrounding the whole filename in quotation mark is enough.

Comment: Also tried that, doesn't help